# Why does jQuery .click() not cause postback when used on this <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

Think this is a quickie for someone. I have this markup (generated by ASP.Net)...

```
<A id=anchorO href="javascript:__doPostBack('anchorO','')">O</A>
```

This anchor is in an update panel, and if I click it manually a partial postback takes place. However....

```
$('[ID$="anchor'+initial+'"]').click()   //JavaScript
```

..selects the correct anchor, but no postback takes place. Why is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26560976/184572

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A click and a href are seen as two different things in Javascript, so you can't do `.click()` and call the href, regardless if this is calling `javascript:` or not

**Two options:**

1. Just do:

   > ```
   > $('#anchor' + initial).click(function() { __doPostBack('anchorO',''); });
   > ```
2. Be evil and use eval:

   > ```
   > $('#anchor' + initial).click(function() { eval($(this).attr('href')); });
   > ```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I actually used the method 1 (evil eval indeed!) however I didn't actually bind it to the click event using `click()` I just force the postback instead of doing any clicking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-handl)

It appears that you can't follow the href of an a tag using the click event.

Comment: +1 Thanks didn't see that question, quite interesting/confusing :)